How to render the dynamic angular code which is stored in a string type variable
["Hello, How are you 

<div *ngIf="csmPage?.buttons?.length > 0" class="button-container">
         
 <div *ngFor="let button of csmPage.buttons">

            <button class="action-button" (click)="onButtonClick(button)">
              {{ button.name }}

            </button>

          </div>

        </div>"]

this is the string
I have stored above mentioned as a string in a variable but when I try to render it then it displays all the code as text.
I want that dynamic buttons should display and work.
I have tried DOM Sanitizer but through that I am getting this output. [Hello, how are you {{button.name}} ] button.name is button but that is not working as it should.

You can not. Angular not "compile at runtime" (well it's possible but it's a hard work and sure there' a better option)

You can render a html string in Angular using the below code.
<div [innerHTML]="htmlString"></div>

You need to ensure you are rendering only hard-coded strings inside this, because this is a security risk, if you render something dynamic like user input, malicious code can be executed.
Also note: Angular events will not work inside this rendered code, since it's rendered outside the Angular context.
If you want Angular events to work, you need to convert the string to just a data object and render the html using this data object dynamically using ngFor, ngSwitch and ngIf.

Some also have to mention that interpreting html code on runtime is an anti-pattern and should be avoided if possible. (Security is one big, but not the only, argument against this). Also you can find an alternative ways often.
